# Advanced features of Microsoft/Facebook authentifcation not available on Asp .Net Core RC1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm working on a small ASP .NET Core RC1 application and I'm trying to implement the Microsoft/Facebook authentification.

The following tutorial is really great and explain all the steps needed:
http://www.oauthforaspnet.com/providers/microsoft/

But if I try to use the "advanced" features (like using the Provider property), this one is not available. I've added the following Nuget references in project.json:

"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-rc1-final",

But I'm not able to use the FacebookAuthenticationProvider / FacebookProvider.

According to my research over the Net, it looks like that was possible using Beta 7 / Beta 8 but does anyone have successfully implemented the feature in RC 1?

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody is using advanced features of ASP .NET Identify in ASP .NET 5 / RC1 ? :)

Comment: Patience, mère de toutes les vertus ;)

Comment: Les français ne sont pas connus pour leur patience... ;-)

Merci pour la réponse en tout cas!

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET Core 1.x, all the OAuth2 social providers ([even the ones developed by the community](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers)) have been updated to use the new OAuth2 generic middleware.

As part of this change, [we've removed the provider-specific classes to use a single events hook named `OAuthEvents`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/pull/257), which replaces Katana's `FacebookAuthenticationProvider` and co.

Here's an example using the Google provider:

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
{
    ClientId = "client_id",
    ClientSecret = "client_secret",

    Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnCreatingTicket = context =>
        {
            // Extract the "language" property from the JSON payload returned by
            // the user profile endpoint and add a new "urn:language" claim.
            var language = context.User.Value<string>("language");
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:language", language));

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @Pinpoint is it possible to utilize multiple authentication methods (i.e. OpenID, Facebook, etc.) at the same time.   For example, give users the option of what account to use?

Comment: @eat-sleep-code sure. But I'm not sure to see how it's related to this specific question.