# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google Add provider

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

How to add A `Provider` in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google`

I can not find any possibility to add Provider like in old way:

```
 public class GoogleAuthProvider : IGoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
    {
        public void ApplyRedirect(GoogleOAuth2ApplyRedirectContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
        }

        public Task Authenticated(GoogleOAuth2AuthenticatedContext context)
        {           
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public Task ReturnEndpoint(GoogleOAuth2ReturnEndpointContext context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
```

If is not possible can I somehow extend `GoogleOptions` and add Provider?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advanced features of Microsoft/Facebook authentifcation not available on Asp .Net Core RC1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623873/advanced-features-of-microsoft-facebook-authentifcation-not-available-on-asp-ne)

Answer (score 1):

Change from:
  context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
To:
  context.Properties.RedirectUri = context.RedirectUri;

Hope it helps.